# Visualizing convoluational layers in autoencoder

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, visualization, autoencoder, keras-2

I have built a variational autoencoder using 2D convolutions (Conv2D) in the encoder and decoder. I'm using Keras. In total I have 2 layers with 32 and 64 filters each and a a kernel size of 4x4 and stride 2x2 each. My input images are (64, 80, 1). I'm using the MSE loss. Now, I would like to visualize the individual convolutional layers (i.e. what they learn) as done [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py).

So, first I load my model using `load_weights()` function and then I call `visualize_layer(encoder, 'conv2d_1')` from above mentioned code where `conv2d_1` is the layer name of the first convolutional layer in my encoder.

When I do so I'm getting the error message

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/BiasAdd}}]]
```

When I use the VGG16 model as in the example code it works. Does somebody know how I can adapt the code to work for my case?

Comment: please add code

Comment: Try to determine the type of convolution first? Manually dissect the model object (encoder object) to get the convolution(s). After that, try to visualize each. If successful, think about how to do the group.